# Angular 8 httpclient response header empty for POST method

Tags: post, header, httpclient, response, angular8

I have enabled Access-Control-Expose-Headers from my backend. But still in angular 8 http client POST method call , response headers are empty.

it always shows

```
HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/auth/login", ok: true, …}
headers: HttpHeaders
normalizedNames: Map(0)
[[Entries]]
No properties
size: (...)
__proto__: Map
lazyUpdate: null
lazyInit: () => {…}
__proto__: Object
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/auth/login"
ok: true
```

Comment: what are you trying to get the response headers in your component? Add some code

Comment: Custom header, which i already enabled in allowd-headers and expose-header at backend

res.headers.get('x-auth-token')

Comment: what's the header key? Did you try something like `response.headers.get('yourKey')`?

Comment: Im trying to get my custm header x-auth-token from headers. x-auth-token is my key

Answer (score 0):

In your Angular app where you're sending the request, pass an object `{observe: 'response'}`.

```
http
  .post<any>('url', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response.headers.get('x-auth-token'));
  });
```

Comment: I already enabled observe as response. It showing all details but not headers

Comment: what do you see in the log? `console.log(response.headers.get('x-auth-token'));`

Comment: hmm, make sure you're sending a response header from the backend.